# Detect if MFC control has insufficient width to hold text (and text will be truncated)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

MFC doesn't have layouts, so controls have to be fixed size and position.

When localizing for a new language, I edit the .rc files directly, but if the text for the new language is longer than the control's width will allow, it gets truncated.

This requires me to do manual inspection of each control to see if it has sufficient width, which is both time-consuming and error-prone.

Right now I'm thinking about adding some code to enumerate all controls, get their text, and see what its width would be, and compare that to the control's width.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Fellow MFC developer here. *Is there a better way?* Don't use MFC.

Comment: This is in my day job, however. At home I can use whatever I want, but here I use this. Since you are a fellow MFC developer, you will understand :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can handle this by using following example of layout,
[Layout Manager for Dialogs, Formviews, DialogBars and PropertyPages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/116/Layout-Manager-for-Dialogs-Formviews-DialogBars-an).Check the size of max text and re-arrange controls according to control.Hope it will work.

Comment: It would take me more time to rewrite the code for my dialogs than to manually inspect everything. But it's good knowing about it, thanks all the same. Great answer.